# How to deal with high redundancy in Neo4j?

Tags: sqlite, graph, neo4j

I am working on an application that uses both relationnal and graph databases (sqlite and neo4j). I am trying to see if I can't get rid of sqlite to use only neo4j, and I am confronted to a problem of redundancy.

Let say I have nodes that represent audio tracks. I want to store of what musical genre each track is. With hundreds of thousands of nodes, I don't think repeating *"South-African Psytrance"* as a string property is a good idea, and I am pretty sure that creating a *"South-African Psytrance"* node and linking it to all concerned nodes is an even worse idea (bottleneck?).

Am I right if I say that using **1) properties** takes too much space, and using **2) relationships** is a bad design for this particular problem?

The current code uses the sqlite db to store a set of musical genres, and their indexes as properties in nodes (which are converted to their string representation in the application layer).

Is there a way to use only neo4j and avoid bottlenecks and redundancy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 is definitely NOT the way to go, as it will waste space and is antithetical to good graph DB design.

Option 2 is the classic way you would do this with a graph DB. There are many examples of neo4j DBs with very large numbers of relationships per node. And neo4j currently supports up to [34 billion](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/capabilities-capacity.html) relationships in a DB, so there is little danger that you will exceed a capacity limit. So, I would recommend that you at least try using this approach.

There are also a few blogs about people using neo4j for storing similar data. For example:

- http://neo4j.com/blog/musicbrainz-in-neo4j-part-1/
- http://neo4j.com/blog/fun-with-music-neo4j-and-talend/
- http://neo4j.com/blog/upload-last-fm-data-neo4j-rneo4j-transactional-endpoint/

[EDITED]

As the slides mentioned by @Pawamoy imply, there is actually a third option. That is, you can create a specific node label for each genre, and apply the appropriate genre label (a node can have more than one) to every track node. This would allow you to avoid using relationships for genres. However, it would tend to "muddy" the label space, since labels at least feel like "node types", and a "music genre" is not an "album track". Also, neo4j supports a [very limited number](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/neo4j/143ybth527/maximum-for-labels) of labels per node, and the maximum number of labels in a DB is also relatively small. So, I would not use this approach unless there was a definite advantage to doing so and the capacity limits are not an issue.

Comment: Agree.  OP's idea of "bottlenecks" doesn't really apply here.  That concept is mis-applied; putting rels through a node does not constitute a "bottleneck" in any meaningful way. What it boils down to is neo4j makes it easy and performant to use nodes and rels, so that should be a go-to approach.

Comment: Very interesting links, thank you! About bottlenecks: it's what I read on the 19th of [these slides](http://fr.slideshare.net/thobe/building-applications-with-a-graph-database). I was afraid that several thousands of relationships on one node would affect performance. I'll accept this answer as solution and give it a try ;)

Comment: Interesting. I have added more thoughts to my answer.

Comment: I did some tests through neo4j web console: I was able to add 100+ labels on one node, some of them using apostrophes, extended-ascii characters like ï, ê, µ, and even chinese characters 漢字. It was also possible to match them back using these same labels.